# Люди - это два и более или один человек?

Tags: множественное-число

Я работаю крановщиком (машинистом башенного крана). Меня наказал технадзор от предприятия, в котором я работаю (лишил в этом месяце премии, а она составляет половину зарплаты).
Ситуация была такая: я поднял  люльку (прямоугольная форма с бортами, то есть с ограждениями), в которой находился стропальщик (стропальщик был один в ней).
А в инструкции (производственная инструкция №5 для машинистов башенного крана) написано (цитирую): "крановщику запрещается поднимать людей или груз с находящимися на нём людьми". 
Правильно ли я понимаю, что люди - это множественное число и понимается как два и более? А я поднял в люльке той одного, а это уже единственное число, значит один.
Вопрос: люди - это два и более (человека)?; люди - это может быть один человек?

Comment: Людей убивать нельзя, но одного человека – можно.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае "люди" - это любое количество. 
На вопрос "сколько у вас людей [было в люльке]?" вы же вполне разумно ответите "один (человек)", "два человека", "пять человек" и так далее. Не важно, сколько их было, но они были.

Лингвистический смысл вам, наверное, не очень интересен, но всё-таки. 
Люди - это множественное число от слова "человек", а "человек" к тому же еще и так называемая "счетная форма" к слову "люди". Когда точное число неизвестно или не имеет значения (в том числе в вопросах и обобщающих формулировках), используется форма множественного числа, что и было сделано в инструкции.

Вот пример - почти полная аналогия. ***"Работники, имеющие детей, могут приобрести путевки в летний лагерь" - кому-то придет в голову отказывать работнику с одним ребенком на том основании, что у него якобы нет детей?!***

Оффтопом.
*Лингвистическая экспертиза бесполезна, при такой постановке вопроса решение, очевидно, будет не в вашу пользу, если вообще возьмутся, а адвокат может помочь, но именно как адвокат, не как лингвист: надо разобраться, правильно ли акт составлен о нарушении ТБ, имеет ли юридическую силу сама инструкция, правомочен ли сам орган (внутренний технадзор), наложивший взыскание, что говорит Трудовой Кодекс, оговорено ли подобное коллективным договором или контрактом...  По опыту знаю, что любая помарка при оформлении такого рода бумаг работодателем однозначно трактуется в пользу работника. Если зарплата у вас "белая", конечно.*

Answer (score 1):

Люди - это обобщённое название представителей вида Homo sapiens sapiens (Человек разумный разумный), независимо от их количества. Неважно сколько человек вы поднимали, одного, двух или сотню, они всё равно были людьми, поэтому премии вас лишили на вполне законных основаниях.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, но всё равно люди и человек это разные понятия я думаю. Подскажите пожалуйста. Я всё таки хочу отправить слово "люди" на экспертизу, к какому специалисту лучше обратиться?

Comment: Экспертиза обойдётся в копеечку. Кстати, деньги — это две или более копеек? Или и копейка — уже деньги?

Comment: @Александр экспертизу проводит эксперт. Эксперты в вопросах языка  обычно обитают на филологических факультетах, но сперва рекомендую обратиться к адвокату, специализирующемуся на трудовых спорах, он вам уже подскажет  порядок оформления экспертизы, да и имеет ли она вообще смысл в виду устоявшейся юридической практики.

Answer (score 1):

Александр, вы подняли-таки "людей" - в количестве одного человека.